# What does refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master mean?

Tags: git, netbeans, git-push

As a rule, I use Git via command line. Today, I decided to use it with NetBeans IDE which generated the following command:

```
git push ssh://...myrepo.git/ refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

Could anyone explain what `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master` means?

Comment: [glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefspecarefspec), [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt), [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203).

Comment: Note: search the glossary for *refspec*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) used is as follows: `git push <repository> <src-ref>:<dst-ref>`

By using `refs/heads/master` as both `<src-ref>` and `<dst-ref>`, Git works with *qualified and explicit [refspecs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)* (locally and on the remote) and does not need to guess the namespace based on source and destination *refspecs*. Additionally, the repository is explicitly provided which means that it is not addressed by a configured name (like `origin`).

---

Let's see this in action in a demo repository. The branch `dev` is checked out and the remote was removed after cloning. First, we list references in the (explicitly provided) remote repository and see that all refs are pointing to *7b7d5a3*.   The log of *git-push* shows that we update `7b7d5a3..4a27218` on the remote `master` branch while no remote is configured and standing on the `dev` branch. Listing the references on the remote again confirms this.

```
$ git branch -va
* dev    7b7d5a3 Initial commit
  master 4a27218 Add file.txt

$ git ls-remote git@domain.tld:user/repo.git
7b7d5a33d6e6ea3d69d9f87fa8ef1c596a37e24c    HEAD
7b7d5a33d6e6ea3d69d9f87fa8ef1c596a37e24c    refs/heads/dev
7b7d5a33d6e6ea3d69d9f87fa8ef1c596a37e24c    refs/heads/master

$ git push -v git@domain.tld:user/repo.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Pushing to git@domain.tld:user/repo.git
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 294 bytes | 294.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To domain.tld:user/repo.git
   7b7d5a3..4a27218  master -> master

$ git ls-remote git@domain.tld:user/repo.git 
4a272186f7f56f2346fb2df7e63584f09936bdad    HEAD
7b7d5a33d6e6ea3d69d9f87fa8ef1c596a37e24c    refs/heads/dev
4a272186f7f56f2346fb2df7e63584f09936bdad    refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 3):

You're pushing the branch called 'master' locally to a remote repo where the branch is also called 'master'.

Normally, your branch would have an upstream in which case this syntax would not be necessary.